# Bootstrap Column Alignment with Resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to make a list using bootstrap columns so that it looks like:

```
    Red:    Apple
    Green:  Grass
    Blue:   Ocean
```

The problem I'm having is that if the text overflows in the right column onto the next line the left column no longer matches up with the text on the right. I thought about using a bootstrap table, but I'm not sure I like the look and the spacing.

To get a better idea about what I'm talking about you can check my live site at [website](http://ryanhutton.me)

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">
    Red:
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">
    Apple
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">
    Green:
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">
    Grass
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">
    Blue:
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">
    Ocean
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted